# Integration after differentiation of exponential to exponential

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the following complex form. I will really appreciate the way to solve it. I have tried and failed myself. My results do not even qualify to be mention here.

\begin{equation}
P = e^{-ne^{- \sigma \lambda t}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} t \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}\ dt
\end{equation}

This is part of the paper I am trying to solve. 
The solution that the author has given is

\begin{equation}
E(t) =  \frac{1}{\sigma \lambda} \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k+1}  {{n} \choose {k}} \frac{1}{k} 
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you sure that there is no typo ? According to a CAS, the results do not match.

Comment: Yes it seems what I have written is correct. The authors have (in my very critically observed opinion missed the $\sigma$ factor in its equation and I have put it there. I just need to learn the method to solve it. Even if it is wrong, if I know how to solve it, I will solve it myself then !!!!

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper ? What is surprising is that both expressions have closed forms (which are not the same).

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7132787

You should be looking for eq. 4 and eq. 5

Can you leave the final answer for the moment and please provide me the solution in your own way...whatever it is. I just want to know the method of how to solve it. I can then track the problem in the paper.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot access the paper.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented earlier, I think that there is a problem.

Since Olivier Oloa answered your [next question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405214/definite-integral-of-the-following-term-with-ee)
$$\int^\infty_0 t(n\lambda e^{-ne^{-\lambda t} - \lambda t})dt=-\frac{n}{\lambda}\int_0^1\log( u) \:e^{-nu}du=\frac{\log (n)+\Gamma (0,n)+\gamma }{\lambda }$$ making $$E(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} t\ \frac{d P}{dt}\ dt=\frac{\log (n)+\Gamma (0,n)+\gamma }{  \sigma \lambda}$$ where appears the announced incomplete gamma function.

But 
$$ \frac{1}{\sigma \lambda} \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k+1}  {{n} \choose {k}} \frac{1}{k} =\frac{\psi ^{(0)}(n+1)+\gamma}{\sigma \lambda}$$ where appears the  digamma function.

These two expressions are not the same. Just for illustration, consider $$\Delta_n=\log (n)+\Gamma (0,n)-\psi ^{(0)}(n+1)$$ and let us compute a few values 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n &\log (n)+\Gamma (0,n) & \psi ^{(0)}(n+1)& \Delta_n \\
 1 & 0.21938 & 0.42278 & -0.20340 \\
 2 & 0.74205 & 0.92278 & -0.18074 \\
 3 & 1.11166 & 1.25612 & -0.14446 \\
 4 & 1.39007 & 1.50612 & -0.11604 \\
 5 & 1.61059 & 1.70612 & -0.09553 \\
 6 & 1.79212 & 1.87278 & -0.08066 \\
 7 & 1.94603 & 2.01564 & -0.06962 \\
 8 & 2.07948 & 2.14064 & -0.06116 \\
 9 & 2.19724 & 2.25175 & -0.05452 \\
 10 & 2.30259 & 2.35175 & -0.04916
\end{array}
\right)$$