# Definite Integral of the following term with $e^e$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

If anyone can help me solve the following equation I will really appreciate it.
It is not part of any assignment or DIY kind of thing. I am trying to solve one research paper and it is part of the bigger problem. Seriously stuck here for two days.

$\int^\infty_0 t(n\lambda e^{-ne^{-\lambda t} - \lambda t}) dt$

Appreciate

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\int^\infty_0 t(n\lambda e^{-ne^{-\lambda t} - \lambda t}) \color{red}{dt} ?
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What makes you expect a closed form?

Comment: The results in the paper.

Comment: Have a look to my answer in your previous post.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. By making the change of variable
$$
u=e^{-\lambda t},\, (\lambda>0)\qquad du= -\lambda e^{-\lambda t}dt, \qquad -\lambda t=\ln u,
$$ you obtain
$$
\int^\infty_0 t(n\lambda e^{-ne^{-\lambda t} - \lambda t})dt=-\frac{n}{\lambda}\int_0^1\ln u \:e^{-nu}du
$$ then by the change of variable $v=nu$ you get an answer in terms of the [Euler constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) and in terms of the [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I understand your point to an extent, still I cannot fully solve this (may be I am getting more dumber...) can you please explain a bit more!